# Define Piecewise Function as a Constraint in Julia

Tags: optimization, julia, constraints, piecewise, julia-jump

I have an optimization model to which I need to add the following piecewise function as a constraint:

```
C_{i,k} = { PR_{i} * HSE_{k} i∈Ω, k = 1,...,M,    
            1                i∈Ω, k = 1,...,M
```

I read PR and HSE from excel cells

¿Is there a nice way to do this in Julia?
I have not found any documentation on this in Julia

Comment: This does not look like a piecewise linear function.  Do you mean `c[i,k]=1 OR c[i,k]=PR[i]*HSE[k]`?

Comment: Yes, this exactly https://ibb.co/pLW5FfJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **piecewise linear function** is something like:

```
  f(x) = a⋅x+b  for x <= p
         c⋅x+d  for x > p
```

There may be more segments.

You describe just an **OR** (not a piecewise linear function):

```
  C[i,k] = PR[i]⋅HSE[k]  OR 1
```

What you describe can be modeled with an extra **binary variable** `δ[i,k] ∈ {0,1}` as:

```
   C[i,k] = (PR[i]⋅HSE[k])⋅δ[i,k] + (1-δ[i,k])
```

This is linear, as PR and HSE are constants. I assume that `C` is a decision variable.